# Can someone help me explain this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

Although the sea level has risen by 6.5 inches since 1950, nearly half of it has occurred in only the last 20 years.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is badly written. As it stands, it is not clear what 'it' refers to. Better would be: Although the sea level has risen by 6.5 inches since 1950, nearly half of **the increase** has occurred in only the last 20 years.